# PDO MYSQL Prepared Update Statement using PHP Not executing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to execute a prepared statement using a PDO via PHP on a MySQL database.

I have tried two versions of the code both have not worked. The function update will execute but nothing will get updated in the database. My view customerData functions using fetch() and fetchAll() both work as does my deleteData function.

My current database structure is:

```
customerID(int11)
firstName(varchar(50)
lastName(varchar(50)
address(varchar(50)
city(varchar(50)
state(varchar(50)
postalCode(varchar(20)
countryCode(char(2)
phone(varchar(20)
email(varchar(50)
password(varchar(20)
```

The current version of code I am using:

```
function update_customer($customerID, $firstName, $lastName, $address, $city, $state, $postalCode, $countryCode, $phone, $email, $password)
{   
  global $db;
    $query = "UPDATE customers
                  SET
                      firstName = :first,
                      lastName = :last,
                      address = :add,
                      city = :c,
                      state = :s,
                      postalCode = :postal,
                      countryCode = :country,
                      phone = :p,
                      email = :e,
                      password = :password
                  WHERE customerID = :ID";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':first',$firstName);
    $statement->bindValue(':last', $lastName);
    $statement->bindValue(':add', $address);
    $statement->bindValue(':c' ,$city);
    $statement->bindValue(':s',$state);
    $statement->bindValue(':postal', $postalCode);
    $statement->bindValue(':country',$countryCode);
    $statement->bindValue(':p', $phone);
    $statement->bindValue(':e', $email);
    $statement->bindValue(':pass', $password);
    $statement->bindValue(':ID', $customerID);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}
```

The other version of code I have used

```
function update_customer($customerID, $firstName, $lastName, $address, $city, $state, $postalCode, $countryCode, $phone, $email, $password)
{
    global $db;
    $query = "UPDATE customers
                  SET
                      firstName = ?,
                      lastName = ?
                      address = ?,
                      city = ?,
                      state = ?,
                      postalCode = ?,
                      countryCode = ?,
                      phone = ?,
                      email = ?,
                      password = ?
                  WHERE customerID = ?";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam('ssssssssssi', $firstName, $lastName, $address, $city, $state, $postalCode, $countryCode, $phone, $email, $password, $customerID);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
}
```

My other 3 prepared statements work perfectly, for example here is the prepared statement that populates the update customer form.

```
function view_customerData ($customerID) {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers
                  WHERE customerID = $customerID";
    try {
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $customerData = $statement->fetch();
        return $customerData;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo "<p>Database error: $error_message </p>";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: specify the param for customerID as integer just to be safe $statement->bindValue(':ID', $customerID,PDO::Param_INT); Note the place holder you're using on password dont match as @Being Sunny has highlighted .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the whole update customer  code on `try` block and put `catch` block if any error occurs. But first of all fix this line

```
$statement->bindValue(':pass', $password);
```

to

```
 $statement->bindValue(':password', $password); 
                             ^^^^

try {
 //.....put your update customer code here ...
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo "<p>Database error: $error_message </p>";
    exit();
}
```